# How to do a merge update in excel across tabs

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

All:

I have one excel file with two tab in it:

**tab1** has something like:

```
BOOK_ID        OWNED
001            false
002            false
003            false
004            true
```

**tab2** has something like:

```
BOOK_ID        OWNED    SHOP 
001            true     S1
001            false    S2
002            false    S1
003            true     S1
004            true     S2
```

What I want to do is update tab1 OWNED column based on the rule:
**AS LONG AS THERE IS AT LEASE ONE SHOP OWNED THAT BOOK in tab2, WE UPDATE THE OWNED COLUMN AS TRUE in tab1**

SO tab1 will be updated to :

```
BOOK_ID        OWNED
001            false->true
002            false
003            false->true
004            true
```

**How can I do this in Excel with VBA or some built-in function?**

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks, could u give me one example, I never used excel function before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following formula in B2 on Tab1:

```
=COUNTIFS(Tab2!A:A,A2,Tab2!B:B,"True")>0
```

And copy down.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let u know if this works, btw, what should I change in your formula, if in the real case, the true is presented as "YES" while false as "NO"?

Comment: Change the `"True"` to `"YES"`